# How to find the locus of this?

Tags: geometry, circles, locus

[image]

Here, in Q4, how to find locus? I took one vertex as $(a,0)$ and other as $(0,b)$ and centroid as $(x, y)$. I am getting these two equations and am unable to eliminate $a$ and $b$ completely-

[image]

Comment: you need a third equation. maybe $a^2+b^2=2$

Comment: I used that. I wrote third vertex in terms of a, b, x and y. Applied distance formula everywhere. Used slopes multiplication =-1. Still not getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one endpoint of the hypotenuse is $A=(t,0)$, then the other endpoint is $B=\big(0,\sqrt{2-t^2}\big)$ and the midpoint of $AB$ is then $M={1\over2}\big(t,\sqrt{2-t^2}\big)$.

If $G$ is the triangle centroid, then $MG$ is perpendicular to $AB$ and $MG=\sqrt2/6$. It follows that the coordinates of $G$ are:
$$
G=\left(
{1\over2}t+{1\over6}\sqrt{2-t^2},{1\over2}\sqrt{2-t^2}+{1\over6}t
\right),
$$
which is then the parametric equation of the locus.

To eliminate $t$, just notice that the coordinates of $G$ satisfy:
$$
3y-x={4\over3}\sqrt{2-t^2}
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
3x-y={4\over3}t.
$$
Squaring both equalities and adding the results gives the stated equation.